# No publicar la app en la play store, puede genera el error de falta de inventario de publicidad?

Tags: android-studio, admob, keystore

**Lea paso a comentar mi duda:**

Termine de desarrollar un app en Android Studio, la cual contiene publicidad, para ser más específicos contiene publicidad de tipo banners e Interstitials, utilizando la plataforma publicitaria Admob.

Lo que me ocurre es lo siguiente: Cambié los id de pruebas por los id de los bloques de anuncios reales y compile la
`app-debug` y la instale en mi móvil para ver como corrían, y corrían perfectamente ambos anuncios, mostrándome anuncios reales de diferentes compañías. Entonces decidí firmar la app y compilar la `app-release` y a la hora de instalarla, correrla en mi móvil las publicidades dejaron de aparecer así que decidí agregar un fragmento de código que me capturara el error y me lo lanzara en un Toast.

Lo que me lanzo el error

`ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL`

que es el que devuelve la constante "3" lo busque en la documentación que esta en linea y resulta ser que este error lo lanza cuando "La solicitud de anuncio se realizó correctamente, pero no se devolvió ningún anuncio debido a la falta de inventario de anuncios."

La duda es la siguiente, **¿por que puede ser que cuando compilo sin firmar la app osea la `app-debug` que se firma una key de prueba los anuncios se muestran correctamente, pero al hora de firmar la app `app-release` con mi key personal que la realizo con el mismo Android Studio, al ejecutarla me aparece el error de falta de inventario?** Como puede ser que con la `app-debug` había inventario, ahora con la `app-release` no tengo inventario y lo único que cambio es que una no está firmada y la otra si (por aíi decirlo ya que se firma con la key de prueba de Android Studio la `app-debug`).

Entonces lo único que me queda por inferir es que al no tener mi app pulicada en la Play store y vinculada con mi cuenta Admob, no me muestra la pulicidad cuando firmo la app con mi firma personal  pero esto dejara de pasar cuando la publique y la vincule con Admob. **¿Estaré en lo correcto?** Si alguien le ha pasado o algo similar que me pueda ayudar le estaré muy agradecido, ya que este tema me tiene desorientado.

Desde ya, muchísimas gracias a Tod@s!!!

**PD:** Tampoco tengo cuenta aun en la plataforma como desabollador.

Answer (score 1):

Me ha ocurrido algo similar, mi caso era el siguiente para uso de VIDEOS BONIFICADOS DE ADMOB en una aplicación de Android Studio:

- Funcionaban bien en desarrollo y recibía los videos sin problema.
- Al publicar mi aplicación en la Google Play Store y descargar de ahí mi propia app para probarla, no recibía ningún video publicitario, pero si un error a través de método: onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(p0: Int) (Tengo un toast en ese método que es el que me avisa del error)

He realizado 2 cosas tras recibir ese error que me lo han resuelto:

1. Vincular mi aplicación a mi cuenta de AdMob (con solo hacer resto seguía sin funcionar)
2. Añadir información de Pagos (es necesaria para que puedas recibir los anuncios). No es necerio poner cuentas hasta no alcanzar los 70€. (Al añadir esta información inmediatamente he empezado a recibir los anuncios).

Si no tienes experiencia con esto, como me ha pasado a mí, te pongo más detalles:

- Entra en Google AdMob
- Menú lateral -> click en Aplicaciones, seleciona la tuya. Ahí te aparece un texto como Vincular con Play Store (no recuerdo el texto exacto)
- Menú lateral -> click en Pagos. Ahí verás que pone Proporciona tus datos... Esta información es necesaria para obtener los anuncios (o un texto similar).